# java stream Collectors.groupingBy() multiple fields

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
Stream<Map.Entry<String, Long>> duplicates = notificationServiceOrderItemDto.getService()
    .getServiceCharacteristics()
    .stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            ServiceCharacteristicDto::getName, Collectors.counting()
        )
     )
     .entrySet()
     .stream()
     .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1);

Optional<String> dupName = duplicates.map(Map.Entry::getKey).findFirst();
```

works perfect. But I wold like to find duplicates not just with name but also name + value + key

> That means if name + value + key is the same this is duplicate.

I am looking Collectors.groupingBy()

http://www.technicalkeeda.com/java-8-tutorials/java-8-stream-grouping

but I can not find correct solution

Answer (score 5):

Following works for me:

```
public class Groupingby
{
    static class Obj{
        String name;
        String value;
        String key;

        Obj(String name, String val, String key)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.value = val;
            this.key = key;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Obj> objects = new ArrayList<>();

        objects.add(new Obj("A", "K", "Key1"));
        objects.add(new Obj("A", "K", "Key1"));
        objects.add(new Obj("A", "X", "Key1"));
        objects.add(new Obj("A", "Y", "Key2"));

        Map<List<String>, Long> collected = objects.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> Arrays.asList(x.name, x.value, x.key), Collectors.counting()));

        System.out.println(collected);
    }

}

// Output
// {[A, K, Key1]=2, [A, Y, Key2]=1, [A, X, Key1]=1}
```

Note that I am using list of attributes for grouping by, not string concatenation of attributes. This will work with non-string attributes as well.

If you are doing string concatenation, you may have some corner cases like attributes (A, BC, D) and (AB, C, D) will result in same string.

Comment: Good answer, the edge cases could probably wreck the other answers :)

Comment: @Lino while you are right, the decision on what this concatenation *must* output is entirely to the OP to decide :)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ServiceCharacteristicDto::getName, Collectors.counting()))
```

you can write

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s->s.getName()+'-'+s.getValue()+'-'+s.getKey(), Collectors.counting()))
```

Comment: This may produce incorrect results. Example: instance with **name=aa value=bb key=cc** will incorrectly be a duplicate of instance with **name=aab value=b key=cc**

Comment: @Michael yes, but if that's an issue,  it can be trivially solved by adding a separator charater between the concatenated fields.

Comment: Yes, true. If you a add a little explanation why the separators are required, I'll delete my comment.

Comment: Well, but why introduce an issue that “can be trivially solved”, when you can simply use `s -> Arrays.asList(s.getName(), s.getValue(), s.getKey())` that has no such issue in the first place? It may even be more efficient than repeatedly doing string concatenation… If you are on Java 9 and can preclude `null` values, you can also use `List.of(…)` which may be even more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

You can replace `ServiceCharacteristicDto::getName` with:

```
x -> x.getName() + x.getValue() + x.getKey()
```

Use a lambda instead of a method reference.

But also think of what findFirst would actually mean here... you are collecting to a HashMap that has no encounter order, streaming its entries and getting the *first* element - whatever that is. You do understand that this `findFirst` can give different results on different input, right? Even re-shuffling the `HashMap` could return you a different `findFirst` result.

**EDIT**

to get away from possible un-intentional duplicates because of String concat, you could use:

```
x -> Arrays.asList(x.getName(), x.getValue(), x.getKey())
```

Comment: See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50872162/java-stream-collectors-groupingby-multiple-fields#comment88746975_50872195) on Eran's answer. Same applies. This is too naive.

Comment: @Michael I can not agree more, good comment. But this is something the OP must decide on...

Comment: @Eugene what kind of decision do you have in mind? To go on with a broken solution?

Comment: @Holger I really don't know, I hoped the OP would jump in and provide a bit more details here :| may be he simply is absolutely sure that the concat would not create confusion

Comment: @Eugene how can anyone be sure about that? Unless that ambiguity is intentional, you could only be sure that this doesn’t break *today* with your current data set. That would be no reason to proceed with a solution that can break tomorrow with different data, especially as other solutions, like `Arrays.asList(…)` are not more complicated and usually even more efficient than string concatenation.

Comment: @Holger - you are right, I can't agree more (but you should see our code base - actually, probably not) and the places where it says - "// I know this list is sorted according to XXX", I will suggest the `ArrayList` though.

Comment: It isn’t that unusual to assume that a list is sorted. After all, you *can* sort a list and afterwards it is sorted but won’t tell you, so you must keep track of that. That’s even expected behavior when calling [`Collections.binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,T,java.util.Comparator))…

Comment: @Holger My point was that for example `getKey` could be actually  `UUID`, so there would not be a need for and `ArrayList`...