# Is this an efficient way to group items by multiple properties and check that another property is either null or not null?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following class that has 3 properties that I'm concerned with:

```
public class Invoice {
    private String invoiceNumber;
    private String vendorCode;
    private BigDecimal vatAmount;
}
```

I need to group them by `invoiceNumber` and `vendorCode` and check that for all of those grouped items, the `vatAmount` is either null for all entries or not null. If either condition fails, I throw a checked exception (`RuleException`). So far I have this:

```
List<Invoice> invoices = ....;

Map<List<String>, List<Invoice>> uniqueInvoiceNumbers = invoices.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e-> Arrays.asList(e.getInvoiceNumber(), e.getVendorCode())));

for (Map.Entry<List<String>, List<Invoice>> entrySet : uniqueInvoiceNumbers.entrySet()) {
    boolean allNull = entrySet.getValue().stream().allMatch(e-> e.getVatAmount() == null);
    boolean allFilled = entrySet.getValue().stream().allMatch(e-> e.getVatAmount() != null);
    if (!allNull && !allFilled) {
        throw new RuleException("The invoices associated with " +  entrySet.getKey().get(0) + " and vendor " + entrySet.getKey().get(1) + " have had their vat amount partially filled. They should either all be filled in or none at all");
    }
}
```

After I've done my check, I discard the grouped items `uniqueInvoiceNumbers` as they are only used for the check.

Is there a better way of doing this? The size of the collection of invoices can range from 1 to 200 items.

---

I've used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50872455/833070) for the code to group by two different keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need one check as “all null” or “all non-null” is about finding a contradicting element. So a list needs at least two elements to be able to have contradicting elements. When you check the first element for `null`, you know, whether all other elements have to be `null` or non-`null`.

```
Optional<List<String>> o = uniqueInvoiceNumbers.entrySet()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1)
    .filter(e -> {
        boolean isNull = e.getValue().get(0).getVatAmount() == null;
        return e.getValue().stream().map(Invoice::getVatAmount)
            .anyMatch(isNull? Objects::nonNull: Objects::isNull);
        })
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .findAny();

if(o.isPresent()) { // can't use ifPresent with checked exception
    List<String> key = o.get();
    throw new RuleException("The invoices associated with "
        +  key.get(0) + " and vendor " + key.get(1)
        + " have had their vat amount partially filled."
        + " They should either all be filled in or none at all");
}
```

You could inline some of the variables used in the code above, which would make this more concise but not necessarily more readable.

---

If you don’t need the `Map<List<String>, List<Invoice>>`, but only collect it for doing this check, you can perform the check while grouping, in one operation, however, due to the checked exception, I’d implement it as a loop instead:

```
List<Invoice> invoices = ....;

Map<List<String>, Boolean> uniqueInvoiceNumbers = new HashMap<>();
for(Invoice i : invoices) {
    List<String> key = Arrays.asList(i.getInvoiceNumber(), i.getVendorCode());
    boolean isNull = i.getVatAmount() == null;
    Boolean existing = uniqueInvoiceNumbers.putIfAbsent(key, isNull);
    if(existing != null && existing != isNull) {
    throw new RuleException("The invoices associated with "
        +  key.get(0) + " and vendor " + key.get(1)
        + " have had their vat amount partially filled."
        + " They should either all be filled in or none at all");
    }
}
```

If `RuleException` was an unchecked exception, we could do something like this:

```
invoices.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        i -> Arrays.asList(i.getInvoiceNumber(), i.getVendorCode()),
        Function.identity(),
        (i1,i2) -> {
            if((i1.getVatAmount() == null) != (i2.getVatAmount() == null)) {
                 throw new RuleException("The invoices associated with "
                    +  i.getInvoiceNumber() + " and vendor " + i.getVendorCode()
                    + " have had their vat amount partially filled."
                    + " They should either all be filled in or none at all");
            }
            return i1;
        }));
```

It’s the same logic, though we can’t just map to a `Boolean` value, as then, the merge function wouldn’t know the keys for the exception message. And, as said, it would require the exception to be unchecked or have to wrap it into another exception, to be extracted outside the stream operation. Which makes the loop variant preferable, unless parallel processing comes into play, which I wouldn’t consider for 200 elements…

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59190592/is-this-an-efficient-way-to-group-items-by-multiple-properties-and-check-that-an?noredirect=1#comment104601253_59190592) would be important information as well, which can help update the grouping pipeline inn itself.

Comment: @Naman I guessed that already, which is why I added the second variant which does operate on the original list.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to use `Pair`

```
Map<Pair<String, String>, List<Invoice>> uniqueInvoiceNumbers = invoices.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> new Pair<>(e.getInvoiceNumber(), e.getVendorCode())));

    Optional<Map.Entry<Pair<String, String>, List<Invoice>>> invalidEntry = uniqueInvoiceNumbers.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(this::isInvalid)
            .findFirst();
    if (invalidEntry.isPresent()) {
        String message = String.format("The invoices associated with %s and vendor %s " +
                "have had their vat amount partially filled. They should either all be " +
                "filled in or none at all", invalidEntry.get().getKey().getKey(), invalidEntry.get().getKey().getValue());
        throw new Exception(message);
    }
```

`isInvalid` method:

```
private static boolean isInvalid(Map.Entry<Pair<String, String>, List<Invoice>> entry) {
    boolean allNull = entry.getValue().stream().allMatch(e -> e.getVatAmount() == null);
    boolean allFilled = entry.getValue().stream().allMatch(e -> e.getVatAmount() != null);
    return !allNull && !allFilled;
}
```

Comment: `Pair` is not available in my current library set and I'd rather not introduce a new library for one check

Comment: I’d stay with a `List<String>` key. Starting with Java 9, you can replace `Arrays.asList` with `List.of` (assuming the strings are never `null`), which will provides at least the performance of a `Pair` type, without the need to change anything else.