# Performing multiple reduction operations using Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm attempting to Stream a list of Objects to aggregate the int min and int max based on the grouping of several Field attributes.

```
public class OccupancyEntry {
    private final int entryID;
    private final String attribute1;
    private final String attribute2;
    private final String attribute3;
    private final int min;
    private final int max;

    public OccupancyEntry(int entryID, String attribute1, String attribute2, String attribute3, int min, int max) {
        this.entryID = entryID;
        this.attribute1 = attribute1;
        this.attribute2 = attribute2;
        this.attribute3 = attribute3;
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }
}
```

I'd like to map the above Objects to a a list of the following:

```
public class OccupancyAggregated {

    private final LocalDate date;
    private final String attribute1;
    private final String attribute2;
    private final String attribute3;
    private final int min;
    private final int max;

    public OccupancyAggregated(LocalDate date, String attribute1, String attribute2, String attribute3, int min, int max) {
        this.date = date;
        this.attribute1 = attribute1;
        this.attribute2 = attribute2;
        this.attribute3 = attribute3;
        this.min = min; //these are summed values
        this.max = max; //these are summed values
    }
}
```

My attempt so far. Through the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50872455/21181303) I've been able to group the entries by a set of fields, but using this method I can no longer get the mapping and reducing functions to work.

```
        OccupancyEntry entry1 = new OccupancyEntry(1, "1", "2", "3", 1, 10);
        OccupancyEntry entry2 = new OccupancyEntry(1, "1", "2", "3", 1, 10);
        OccupancyEntry entry3 = new OccupancyEntry(1, "A", "B", "C", 1, 10);
        
        ArrayList<OccupancyEntry> occupancyEntries = new ArrayList<>();

        occupancyEntries.add(entry1);
        occupancyEntries.add(entry2);
        occupancyEntries.add(entry3);

        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
        ArrayList<OccupancyAggregated> aggregated = new ArrayList<>();


        Map<List<String>, List<OccupancyEntry>> collect = occupancyEntries.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(x -> Arrays.asList(x.getAttribute1(), x.getAttribute2(), x.getAttribute3())));
```

The sought after output. Where the min and max fields are reduced from from the entirety of the grouped OccupancyEntry list.

```
ArrayList<OccupancyAggregated> aggregated = new ArrayList<>();
```

My previous attempts have consisted out of creating multiple streams which reduce either the min field or the max field based on String concatenated attribute fields.

```
        final Map<String, Integer> minOccupancy = occupancyEntries.stream()
                .collect((groupingBy(OccupancyEntry::getGroupedAttributes,
                        mapping(OccupancyEntry::getMin,
                                reducing(0, Integer::sum)))));

        final Map<String, Integer> maxOccupancy = occupancyEntries.stream()
                .collect((groupingBy(OccupancyEntry::getGroupedAttributes,
                        mapping(OccupancyEntry::getMax,
                                reducing(0, Integer::sum)))));
```

Afterwards I'd for loop through one of the maps and then start creating a new list with  OccupancyAggregated objects and look up the values in both maps to construct it. This seemed much too convoluted.

I've also been trying to perform the reduce operation in one pass using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40039399/21181303) answer but I'm not sure how to get it to map to the new Class type properly.

```
occupancyEntries.stream()
               .reduce((x, y) -> new OccupancyAggregated(
                       date,
                       x.getAttribute1(),
                       x.getAttribute2(),
                       x.getAttribute3(),
                       x.getMin() + y.getMin(),
                       x.getMax() + y.getMax()
               ))
               .orElse(new OccupancyAggregated(date, "no data", "no data", "no data", 0, 0));
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you're trying to obtain *per-group* minima and maxima? That seems consistent with the members of your `OccupancyAggregated` class, but not necessarily with "min and max fields are reduced from from the entirety of the grouped OccupancyEntry list."

Comment: What is the expected result for the sample input you provided?

Comment: @JohnBollinger my apologies I can see how my post has caused this confusion. What I'm trying to achieve is to aggregate the values of the respective grouped `OccupancyEntry` min and max member variables to a single instance of the `OccupancyAggregated` Class.

The three `OccupancyEntry` objects instantiated for the example should lead to two new `OccupancyAggregated` instances. The first `min=2` and `max=20` (a reduction of the entries) and the second only contains the reduction of the last entry, being `min=1 max=10`

Comment: @Eritrean the expected result is a `List<OccupancyAggregated>` containing two items. The first item will be the aggregated value of the first two `OccupancyEntry` objects, their min values reduced and their max values reduced, leading to 
```List[0] OccupancyAggregated:min=2, OccupancyAggregated:max=20`

List[1] OccupancyAggregated:min=1
OccupancyAggregated:max=10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common request that's messy to solve with streams, because there's no concept of an "empty" or "identity" instance of the aggregate. I prefer the semi-imperative approach using a loop and `Map.merge()`:

```
Map<List<String>, OccupancyAggregated> grouped = new HashMap<>();
for (OccupancyEntry e : occupancyEntries) {
    grouped.merge(Arrays.asList(e.attribute1, e.attribute2, e.attribute3),
            OccupancyAggregated.from(e, date),
            OccupancyAggregated::merge);
}
List<OccupancyAggregated> aggregated = new ArrayList<>(grouped.values());
```

Where the `merge()` method looks like this:

```
public OccupancyAggregated merge(OccupancyAggregated o) {
    return new OccupancyAggregated(
            date, attribute1, attribute2, attribute3, min + o.min, max + o.max);
}
```

Alternatively, if you can make the aggregate mutable, you can update min/max in place:

```
OccupancyAggregated agg = grouped.computeIfAbsent(
        Arrays.asList(e.attribute1, e.attribute2, e.attribute3),
        attributes -> OccupancyAggregated.from(attributes, date));
agg.add(e.min, e.max);
```

I left out some of the new method implementations for the sake of brevity. Let me know if they need more elaboration.

Comment: Thank you! This is a very concise way of handling the problem. I also appreciate the alternative options in case the aggregate is mutable. I've marked your answer as useful as well but unfortunately I'm too new for it to be publicly visible yet. In terms of the OccupancyAggregated::merge implementation I'm assuming it accepts a OccupancyAggregated instance, adds the min/max fields to the existing instance and returns itself. Unfortunately my implementation doesn't seem to result in the proper merged values as they remain 0. Is it possible to elaborate on your merge implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class AggregateToGetMinMax {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<OccupancyEntry> list = setup();
        List<OccupancyAggregated> result = aggregate(list, LocalDate.now());
        System.out.println("\nresult: " + result);
    }

    public static List<OccupancyEntry> setup() {
        OccupancyEntry[] entries = {
                new OccupancyEntry(1, "1", "2", "3", 1, 10),
                new OccupancyEntry(1, "1", "2", "3", 1, 10),
                new OccupancyEntry(1, "A", "B", "C", 1, 10)
        };

        return List.of(entries);
    }

    public static List<OccupancyAggregated> aggregate(List<OccupancyEntry> occupancyEntries, LocalDate date) {
        class MinMax {
            int max = 0;
            int min = 0;

            public MinMax() {
            }

            public MinMax(OccupancyEntry oe) {
                this.max = oe.max;
                this.min = oe.min;
            }

            public MinMax add(MinMax mm) {
                this.max += mm.max;
                this.min += mm.min;
                return this;
            }

            public String toString() {
                return "min: " + min + "; max: " + max;
            }
        }

        Map<String, List<OccupancyEntry>> groupedEntries = occupancyEntries.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(OccupancyEntry::getGroupedAttributes));

        System.out.println("grouped entries: ");
        groupedEntries.entrySet().stream()
            .forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry));

        List<OccupancyAggregated> result = groupedEntries.values().stream()
            .map(list -> {
                MinMax mm = list.stream()
                    .map(MinMax::new)
                    .reduce(
                        new MinMax(),
                        (MinMax acc, MinMax item) -> acc.add(item));

                // It's okay to get(0) because all entries with have values with at least one item
                // in the list.
                OccupancyAggregated aggregated = new OccupancyAggregated(date, list.get(0), mm.min, mm.max);
                return List.of(aggregated);
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return result;
    }

    public static class OccupancyEntry {

        private final int entryID;
        private final String attribute1, attribute2, attribute3;
        public final int min, max;

        public OccupancyEntry(int entryID, String attribute1, String attribute2, String attribute3, int min, int max) {
            this.entryID = entryID;
            this.attribute1 = attribute1;
            this.attribute2 = attribute2;
            this.attribute3 = attribute3;
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
        }

        public String getGroupedAttributes() {
            return List.of(attribute1, attribute2, attribute3).stream()
                .collect(Collectors.joining("|"));
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "OccupancyEntry [" + entryID + ", " + attribute1 + ", " + attribute2
                + ", " + attribute3 + ", " + min + ", " + max + "]";
        }
    }

    public static class OccupancyAggregated {
        final LocalDate date;
        String attribute1, attribute2, attribute3;
        private int min, max;

        public OccupancyAggregated(LocalDate date, OccupancyEntry oe, int min, int max) {
            this.date = date;
            this.attribute1 = oe.attribute1;
            this.attribute2 = oe.attribute2;
            this.attribute3 = oe.attribute3;
            this.min = min; // these are summed values
            this.max = max; // these are summed values
        }
        
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "OccupancyAggregated: ( " +
                attribute1 + ", " +
                attribute2 + ", " +
                attribute3 + ", " +
                min + ", " +
                max +
                " )";
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I have separated the grouping and reducing so that one can more clearly focus on the reducing part of the work.  Otherwise, building the entire operation straight through might become a bit tedious to mentally parse the important operation.

Output:

```
grouped entries: 
A|B|C=[OccupancyEntry [1, A, B, C, 1, 10]]
1|2|3=[OccupancyEntry [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 10], OccupancyEntry [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 10]]

result: [OccupancyAggregated: ( A, B, C, 1, 10 ), OccupancyAggregated: ( 1, 2, 3, 2, 20 )]
```

The more succinct version of `accumulate()` looks like this:

```
    public static List<OccupancyAggregated> aggregate(List<OccupancyEntry> occupancyEntries, LocalDate date) {
        class MinMax {
            int max = 0;
            int min = 0;

            public MinMax() {
            }

            public MinMax(OccupancyEntry oe) {
                this.max = oe.max;
                this.min = oe.min;
            }

            public MinMax add(MinMax mm) {
                this.max += mm.max;
                this.min += mm.min;
                return this;
            }

            public String toString() {
                return "min: " + min + "; max: " + max;
            }
        }

        List<OccupancyAggregated> result = occupancyEntries.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(OccupancyEntry::getGroupedAttributes))
            .values().stream()
            .map(list -> {
                MinMax mm = list.stream()
                    .map(MinMax::new)
                    .reduce(
                        new MinMax(),
                        (MinMax acc, MinMax item) -> acc.add(item));
        
                // It's okay to get(0) because all entries with have values with at least one item
        // in the list.
            OccupancyAggregated aggregated = new OccupancyAggregated(date, list.get(0), mm.min, mm.max);
            return List.of(aggregated);
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Going through your solution helped me better understand the process behind it and how to implement certain other aspects. I've marked the answer as helpful but unfortunately my account is too new for it to display votes publicly.